# Why can't I open() and parse() this JSON file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am using Django to build a web serivce in Python and one of my tasks is to parse a .json file within my project.

The code compiles but the `var json_data` trying to hold the data becomes null when I try to access the json file.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Network Graph3</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">


 <script>
  // import json;
  window.onload = function () {
   var arr = [];
   var json_data = open("{% static 'static/json/graphData.json' %}");

   var obj = JSON.parse(json_data);
   var i;
   console.log(json_data)
   if (obj == null){
     return
   }
   for (i = 0; i < obj.documents; i++){
     point = obj.documents[i];
     arr[point.id].y = point.score;
   }
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
     animationEnabled: true,
     theme: "light2",
     title:{
         text: "Dialog Sentiment Analysis"
     },
     axisY:{
         includeZero: false
     },
     data: [{
         type: "line",
         dataPoints: arr
         // [
         //     { y: 450 },
         //     { y: 414},
         //     { y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle" },
         //     { y: 460 },
         //     { y: 450 },
         //     { y: 500 },
         //     { y: 480 },
         //     { y: 480 },
         //     { y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross" },
         //     { y: 500 },
         //     { y: 480 },
         //     { y: 510 }
         // ]
     }]
   });
   chart.render();

 }
</script>

</head>
```

The sample json data looks like:

```
{"documents": [{"id": "0", "score": 0.8365770578384399},
            {"id": "2", "score": 0.9896875619888306},
            {"id": "3", "score": 0.5},
            {"id": "4", "score": 0.5},
            {"id": "6", "score": 0.12722820043563843},
            {"id": "7", "score": 0.16494140028953552},
            {"id": "8", "score": 0.7551238536834717},
            {"id": "9", "score": 0.12901419401168823},
            {"id": "10", "score": 0.5},
            {"id": "11", "score": 0.7559014558792114},
```

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript `open()` is for opening URL in new tab/window not reading the content, use `XMLHttpRequest()` or jQuery `$.ajax()` / `.getJSON()`. or you mean want to do python `open()` ?

code for javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      // proccess json here
      readJson(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', "/'static/json/graphData.json=", true);
  xhr.send(null);
}

function readJson(json_data) {
  var arr = [];
  var obj = JSON.parse(json_data);
  var i;
  console.log(json_data)
  ....
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So many issues here...
I'm assuming your code is expected to call the `open()` python function and on this case you cannot call it from javascript context as it will be evaluated to [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) (which has nothing to do with python) rather than python function.

So all you have to do is read json file from [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/) and return back to template context as serialized json string, something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    context = {"data": None}

    with open('data.json') as f:
        context['data'] = json.load(f)


    return render(request, 'templates/my_template.html', context)
```

Now just use `JSON.parse()`.
Another option is rely on [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) if you are using jQuery or similar library or AJAX, fetching json data from server via HTTP (it requires json file has public access via HTTP).